# Is it technically possible for an OPC UA client to tunnel requests to an OPC UA server via a Forward Proxy?

Tags: java, spring-boot, opc-ua, opc, milo

**Issue**

This is the OPC UA MILO client SDK used by my java program: https://github.com/eclipse/milo/blob/master/opc-ua-sdk/sdk-client/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/sdk/client/OpcUaClient.java

I have an OPC UA client sitting behind a Forward Proxy and wants to attempt a connection via a forward proxy to reach the OPC UA server at a TCP port. It is an OPC protocol on top of a TCP connection.

Issue here is the SDK client in the link above does **not** support a forward proxy connection that I could call in code to set up a tunnel for requests to reach the OPC UA server. I have a sense that we will have to move to a new client SDK.

Due to the design of the current infrastructure, any outbound request to external systems will have to be made via this forward proxy, and not a direction connection.

**Intent**

1. I would like to know if it is technically possible for an OPC UA connection to be made from the client to server via a forward proxy. Of course, it is without said that the Forward Proxy would first have to allow the port by ACL configuration. However, my question is still,- Can OPC UA connections allow connections via forward proxy in the first place, because I have done research on this topic, and could not any information regarding this.
2. If point 1 is technically possible, how can I handle this in Java code with the MILO client sdk still intact would be preferable, or point me to a java client SDK that I could use in Java code to allow for a connection to a forward proxy before tunneling the request to the OPC UA server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it’s technically possible if you have Squid configured to act as a SOCKS5 proxy, however Milo uses the Netty library for its networking and Netty doesn’t look for the `socksProxyHost` and related Java system properties by default; it requires that a SOCKS handler is explicitly added to the end of a pipeline. It doesn’t look like this configuration is possible in the current version.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for clarifying. Just wondering, do you have an alternative suggestion to the MILO sdk client? i.e., any other OPC UA client SDK libraries that I could perhaps look into that enables the handling of a forward proxy connection that I could use in code?

Comment: Milo is the only open source implementation of OPC UA in Java. There is one commercial alternative you can surely find by searching, but I have no idea whether they have proxy support.

Comment: Not sure it's a huge help, but I can probably add support for customizing the ChannelPipeline via configuration in the `dev/1.0` version of Milo. This would allow you to add a `Socks5ProxyHandler` to any client connection you want.

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse/milo/pull/1241

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thank you so much, appreciate the help on this! Will test it out! If I need further clarifications, will revert back:)

Comment: The dev branch isn't available in Maven Central, you would have check out the Milo source code and build it yourself. As I said... this probably isn't a huge help. There will also be significant updates required to your codebase coming from `0.4.x`.

Comment: Hi Kevin, as you had said, I have checked out the Milo source code, but upon building (Running mvn clean install) the code, I get a Java version incompability error. I'm currently using java 8 to build and run my java code. but the milo source code at dev/1.0 branch requires java 11. I thought the Milo source code is able to be built with java 8, based on the README text file. Not sure what I'm lacking here. Are there other alternatives besides upgrading to Java 11?

Comment: No, the 1.0 release of Milo currently targets JDK 11 and may target JDK 17 before it is released. Maybe you can consider forking Milo @ whatever 0.4.x release your project uses and backporting that PR I linked above yourself. That is probably the option that will require the least amount of changes to your existing code.